# Warning when mocking a class

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

I am reading this article - https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mocking-with-dart/ - about mocking wiht Dart and have gotten this simple example working.

```dart
import 'package:unittest/mock.dart';

class Foo {
  int x;
  bar() => 'bar';
  baz() => 'baz';
}

class MockFoo extends Mock implements Foo {}

void main() {
  var mockFoo = new MockFoo();
  mockFoo.when(callsTo('bar')).
      thenReturn('BAR');

  print(mockFoo.bar());
}
```

The code prints 'BAR' correctly, so the mocking clearly works. But the Dart Editor generates a warning/error:

```
Missing inherited members: 'Foo.bar', 'Foo.baz' and 'Foo.x'
```

Despite this warning/error, the code seems to work but I would like to get rid of the error. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since MockFoo implements Foo, you need to define `x`, `bar()` and `baz()`, even if you are only interested in the behavior of `bar()`.  For your example, this is as simple as doing the following:

```dart
class MockFoo extends Mock implements Foo {
  int x;
  bar() {}
  baz() {}
}
```

For more substantial classes that contain a long list of members, this pattern can become quite tedious, but I don't know a better way of silencing the Editor warning. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can silence the warnings if you implement `noSuchMethod()`

```dart
class MockFoo extends Mock implements Foo {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    return super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this, you may also want to apply the `@proxy` annotation. Since the Mock class defines noSuchMethod, just appending the `@proxy` annotation to your class _should_ prevent warnings however this doesn't seem to be the case in the latest dev build.

Comment: Thanks @MattB for starting a discussion about that topic on the Dart mailing list where Brian Wilkerson provided an extended explanation [Should `@proxy` suppress noSuchMethod warnings if extending a class which implements noSuchMethod?](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/editor/GIt4ONo7t7E)